# Work with Java 1.7 and 1.8 at the same time

Tags: java

I'm working on Windows 7.

I have projects on my machine that runs with Java 1.7.
I have now checked out an existing project made by someone else that runs with Java 1.8.

I'd like to know the best way to switch from one Java version to another according on which project I work?

Comment: How you run/start the project?

Comment: An installation of Java 8 will also run an application build for Java 7.

Comment: @SasikumarMurugesan The project run under a tomcat server after the war file is generated and deployed.

Comment: All war files are deployed in to same tomcat?

Comment: @SasikumarMurugesan No, not the same, one on tomcat 7, the other tomcat 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can use the `setenv.bat` file, to set your `JRE_HOME` version.

> On Windows, create the file `%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat`, with content:
>
> `set "JRE_HOME=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre1.6.0_20"`
>
> `exit /b 0`

So create the file on both tomcat and set jre location

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which frameworks are you using in these projects. If you talk about `J2SE` java 8 is backward compatible. All the code which is written in `Java 7` is  completely fine with `Java 8`. you don't need to worry about.